# Null pointer exception on the following code

Tags: android

I am a beginer in android and java,can anybody help me to find out the reason of this error in my code plz???

```
serviceSwitch =(Switch) this.findViewById(R.id.switchservice);
serviceSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){

    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked){
        try{
            if(isChecked){
                arrayChecking();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "set date n time ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                  
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("switchfailed",e.toString());
        }
    }       
});
```

Code for arrayChecking
It checks the tbpreferenceArray is empty or not?,If it is empty it shows the toast,else it pass an intent to call background service in my app

```
public void arrayChecking(){

    if(tbPreferenceArray.length>0){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Set the Time and Day", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        serviceSwitch.setChecked(false);        
    }
    else{
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TimerService.class);
        MainActivity.this.startService(i);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();   
    }
}
```

Shared Preference code

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("TogglePreference", 0);  
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();  
    editor.putInt("tbPreferenceArray" +"_size", toggleButtonArray.length); 
    for(int i=0;i<toggleButtonArray.length;i++)
    {
        editor.putBoolean("tbPreferenceArray" + "_" + i, toggleButtonArray[i]);

    }
    editor.commit();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your timetable is ok",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: Please update your post with 'arrayChecking()' code and add logcat error info

Comment: I can see more than variable would be null but you have check logcat .

Comment: Add e.printStackTrace() to your catch block and post the logcat output again

Comment: please post the arrayChecking(); method and all necessary code that belongs to that method.

Comment: Please update your post with 'arrayChecking()' code and string resources in strings.xml

Comment: Are you using this code in activity or fragment

Comment: Are you sure `isChecked`  is not null?

Comment: isChecked could not be null, it´s a parameter of onCheckedChanged() method from the checkedChangeListener

Comment: @Gaetan Maisse: I have updated the code with arraycheking method..plz check it

Comment: where Do You have initialized the tbPreferenceArray ?

Comment: @ @Opiatefuchs:tbPreferenceArray is In  a shared preference

Comment: please post more...we need really see the context for all this coding. What You are doing with this array, where is it initialized and so on....

Comment: where is `R.id.switchservice` defined?

Comment: yes it is defined serviceSwitch =(Switch) this.findViewById(R.id.switchservice);

Comment: @Opiatefuchs: The array has states of some toggle buttons either(True/false),Initially it is saved in toggleButtonArray[] when user clicks the button,and later the array is saved in to tbPreferenceArray[],

Comment: So i want to check the array for values when the user cliks the switch in  my app ,If the array is filled with some values,i want to call the background service

Comment: Debug your code, put a breakpoint first on `serviceSwitch` to check if this is the null variable...

Answer (score 0):

Please correct your code as follow:

```
if(tbPreferenceArray!= null && tbPreferenceArray.length>0)
```